# Remove deleted files from github pull request?

Tags: git, github

I deleted some files locally that were machine generated, but also being tracked. After deletion some time ago, I made multiple commits and made a pull request.

However, contributors want me to remove that deletion part from the commit.

How can I fix that?

Most times I get this error: (git rm, git checkout etc)

`error: pathspec 'filepath' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

File was deleted locally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the commit where you deleted the file:

```
git log -n1 -- path/to/file
```

Restore the file from one commit before the one that deleted it:

```
git checkout SHA1~1 -- path/to/file
```

Repeat for each removed file you want to restore.

Commit, and push to the branch to update the Pull Request (adding one commit).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly you have created a feature branch containing some number of commits, in one of which you deleted some files which you should have not.  In this case, doing an interactive rebase should be a viable option for correcting this problem.  In an interactive rebase, you can amend (among other things) what happened at each commit in the history of your feature branch.  In your case, you would want to undo the deletion of certain files.  Here is how you can do this:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase -i HEAD~4    # replace 4 with however far back is the commit
                        # containing the deletions
```

This should bring up a window showing the five most recent commits made to the `feature` branch:

```
pick 07c5abd message for commit A
pick dl398cn message for commit B
pick 93nmcdu message for commit C
pick lst28e4 message for commit D
pick 398nmol message for commit E
```

Here, the first commit shown is the *oldest*, and the last is the most recent.  You will notice that the default option is `pick`.  Find the commit (say commit `B`) which is the one where you accidentally deleted the files, and replace `pick` with `edit`, leaving you with this:

```
pick 07c5abd message for commit A
edit dl398cn message for commit B
pick 93nmcdu message for commit C
pick lst28e4 message for commit D
pick 398nmol message for commit E
```

Then save the file, which should close this window and the rebase should start.  When Git reaches commit `B`, it should pause, giving you a change to change what you did.  Type `git status`, and you should see the files which you deleted.  To restore a deleted file just use:

```
git checkout HEAD path/to/deleted/file
```

When you have finished restoring the deleted files, type:

```
git rebase --continue
```

This should effectively remove the deletions from your `feature` branch.  There is one final quirk here, which is that since you rewrote the history of `feature`, you have to force push it to the repository via:

```
git push --force origin feature
```

Now your pull request is updated and should hopefully pass scrutiny.